# Omniture Sandbox Request not approved yet

Tags: adobe-analytics

I submitted a request online for Omniture Sandbox after registering at Omniture Developer connection at https://developer.omniture.com/en_US/devcenter but no response yet. I have been waiting for an approval since almost a week now. But no reply yet.

Is this normal ? Is the developer connection still supported by Adobe ?  If no, please guide me how to create a sandbox environment for omniture ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how long it usually takes.. I suggest you contact your ClientCare rep.  But, why not just login to your Adobe Marketing Cloud instance and create a report suite to use as a sandbox?

Comment: What is Adobe Marketing Cloud instance? I registered and created an account developer.omniture.com only. Is there any other place that I need to create an account also ?

Comment: aah.. I'm not sure they they EVER gave sandboxes to people who don't actually subscribe to Adobe Marketing Cloud (formerly known as SiteCatalyst).  I just assumed that you actually subscribe and have Adobe Marketing Cloud (what the sandbox is for).

Answer (score 0):

I've requested access many times over the past year. Just this week I asked our rep about the sandbox and he told me that they no longer did that. Typically my rep hasn't been 100% on information like this so take it with a grain of salt.

If you have a twitter account, try jumping on there and ask about that and include @AdobeMktg #omniture tags and you'll get an answer usually.